# Calculated Point Values for Nomogram in RMS Package

Tags: r, regression

I'm using the `rms`package to draw a nomogram to represent a logistic regression for my model `fit`.

My data structure is

```
'data.frame':   12763 obs. of  11 variables:`
`$ Outcome  : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 ...`
`$ Grade    : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 2 2 2 2 3 2 2 1 2 1 ...`
`$ CF       : Factor w/ 2 levels "10","20": 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...`
`$ HF       : Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 3 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 3 1 ...`

ddist<-datadist(data)
```

`options(datadist='ddist')`

`fit<-lrm(Outcome~Grade+CF+HF, x=TRUE, y=TRUE, data=data)`

The model returns:

```
> fit  
Logistic Regression Model

 lrm(formula = Outcome ~ Grade + CF + HF, data = data, x = TRUE, 
 y = TRUE)

                   Model Likelihood     Discrimination    Rank Discrim.    
                      Ratio Test           Indexes           Indexes       
Obs         12763    LR chi2    3720.22    R2       0.480    C       0.878    
 1          11185    d.f.             6    g        1.764    Dxy     0.757    
 3           1578    Pr(> chi2) <0.0001    gr       5.834    gamma   0.853    
max |deriv| 2e-08                          gp       0.166    tau-a   0.164    
                                        Brier    0.065                     

        Coef    S.E.   Wald Z Pr(>|Z|)
Intercept -0.1894 0.0528  -3.59 0.0003  
Grade=2   -2.5917 0.0740 -35.02 <0.0001 
Grade=3   -4.1537 0.1385 -29.98 <0.0001 
CF=20      2.9472 0.0981  30.03 <0.0001 
HF=2      -1.1445 0.1494  -7.66 <0.0001 
HF=3      -1.0875 0.1771  -6.14 <0.0001 
HF=4      -0.0019 0.1931  -0.01 0.9920  
>
```

I print the nomogram and receive the following points for each level of my predictors:

```
> nom<-nomogram(fit)
> print(nom)
Points per unit of linear predictor: 24.07491 
Linear predictor units per point   : 0.04153701 


 Grade Points
 1     100   
 2      38   
 3       0   


 CF Points
 10  0    
 20 71    


 HF Points
 1  28    
 2   0    
 3   1    
 4  28    
>
```

My first question is about the point values assigned `Grade`.
If I were drawing this nomogram by hand from the Beta coefficients in my model `fit`, I would identify my highest B coefficient -4.1537(Grade=3) and the next highest B coefficient 2.9472 (CF=20).

Then divide the two to arrive at a point value:
2.9472/4.1537=0.71.  71 is the point value is equal to CF 20. This matches the points on the nomogram.

To calculate the next point value, I select the third highest B coefficient, -2.5917 (Grade=2).

-2.5917/-4.154=.624. The nomogram assigned 38 to Grade=2 instead of 63. I do not understand how this value is 38 and I'm sure I'm missing something.

My second question is about the Total Points calculation of 220. If I select the predictor values with the highest possible points - Grade 1+CF 20+ HF 4 - (or 100+71+28) my total points would be 199.  Why would the total points scale go to 220 when there is no combination of values that equal 220 points?

Thank you for any help. I appreciate your time.

Comment: Please see the answer [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/250050/calculated-point-values-for-nomogram)